FormBuilder: Required rule for birth date that is in form builder page is not working
Required rule for birth date or date field in general that is in form builder page is not working.
It will not prompt that the field is required when there is no selected value for it. Which then continues to submit it. Then backend will respond with status code 200 but has data of:
{"error_code":0,"error_message":"Validation Error","status":500}.
This Validation Error (based on logs) indicates that the birth date field is a required field.
Also, if the form builder settings had Post-Submit Page entry, it would also reroute to it even though there was a validation error.
CiviCRM: 5.76.2
WordPress: 6.6.1
Fresh Install/Setup

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31028
Made a PR. Seems like the attribute was missed for Date field.
